# In React, Id pass in URL Parameter but not get in API Parameter Not even hit the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Need to pass the ID from One Page to another Page API. It is pass in Parameter but not hit the API.  This is my first Page

```
<Link to={"/Editpage.js/?group_Id="+item.group_Id} title="Edit" >Edit</Link>&nbsp;
  <Link to={"/GroupsDetail.js/"+item.group_Id} title="Details" >Details</Link>&nbsp;
```

In another Page it pass in Parameter "http://localhost:3001/Editpage.js/29"

```
const urll = new URL(window.location.href);
  const Id = urll.searchParams.get("group_Id");
  console.log(Id);
    let url = 'http://localhost:XXXXX/api/Group/EditprofileloggedUser?Group_Id='+Id;
```

It hit the API but id pass as a null value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWJXD.png)
Share your Idea.

Comment: Since you already use some sort of framework (cause of Link component), you should check and use its API to get the params. Look for some kind of useParams hook

Comment: Have you tried in the 1st snippet to remove the `/` bfore `group_id` and in the 2nd snippet to rename `Group_Id`  to `group_id` ?  Can you provide a reproducible codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Okay I try it and ley you know

Comment: No API is not hit. I remove / and Group_Id to group_Id but it didn't work @Dimitri Kopriwa.

Comment: Are you using `react-router` ? `Link` is supposed to be used for frontend routing,.

Comment: Yes using  react-router but <a/> is not working in hosting side so I use the Link

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You can pass state with the Link-component from the 'react-router-dom' like this:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: "/myPage",
  state: { id: 123 }
}}>Edit</Link>
```

then on the site "myPage", you can get that passed state like this:

```
    import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
    
    const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(location.state) {
      console.log(location.state.id)
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + location.state.id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    }
  },[location.state])
```

A better option would be to implement a global state with Redux for example or useContext.

Comment: Need to pass in URL also @OutlawSloth

Comment: the URL is passed in the object in the "to"-prop: 

<Link to={{
  pathname: "/myPage",
  state: { id: 123 }
}}>Edit</Link>

Comment: Not hit API @OutlawSloth

Comment: I've edited my answer with a working API-call. It's a working example. Maybe you could follow that example and then apply it to your project.

What is not working? is the state undefined?

Comment: I need to Pass Get API Id  in the URL. It shows Undefined in URL and Not hit the API

Comment: the "id" is being passed as a state with the Links prop "to". The state can then be retrieved and used on the page later with the "useLocation()"-hook, as you can see in the answer. Is the state undefined on the page you mean? What does the object look like if you log it?

Comment: Okay I'll try it one. I'm a beginner I try it @OutlawSloth

Comment: post the code here that you are trying and I'll show you why it's not working. Trust me, it works, I have it working on my end ;)

Comment: <Link to={"/GroupsDetail.js/?group_Id="+item.group_Id}>Details</Link> This is My group Page When I click this button it pass the Id in URL Parameter "http://localhost:3000/#/GroupsDetail/?group_Id=31" . It pass the Id null in API  in console like "http://localhost:49590/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id=null" .... This is my API call Function  const urll = new URL(window.location.href);
      const Id = urll.searchParams.get("group_Id");
              
              console.log(Id);
        let url = 'http://localhost:49590/api/Group/GroupDetailsDisplay?group_Id='+Id;

Comment: It hit the API but ID id is null.